# Manage SQL on several computers

Tags: java, mysql, sql, data-migration

Im sure this is a common problem but I am not familiar with any java frameworks useful to solving it. The problem is:

I have a java project which many people are working on deploying a web app to a jboss server hooked up to a MySQL Locale database for testing reasons.

Currently whenever a database migration is made by a team member an email is sent out to the team to perform the same migration on their local database.

Is there a java framework similar to in ruby where we can check in the SQL and run a mvn goal or something to perform the change to our local mysql instance if it hasnt already been applied?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the "[Flywaydb](http://flywaydb.org/)" platform.